# Tensorflow Object Detection - Convert .pb file to tflite

Tags: python, tensorflow, converters, tensorflow-lite, toco

I try to convert a frozen SSD mobilenet v2 model to TFLITE format for android usage.
Here are all my steps:

1. I retrain with **TF Object Detection API**'s train.py file using the **ssd_mobilenet_v2_coco_2018_03_29** model frok the model zoo. **(OK)**
2. Export the trained model.ckpt to frozen model file using **export_inference_graph.p**y also provided by TF Object Detection API. **(OK)**
3. Test the frozen graph in python with GPU and also with only CPU allowed. It works. **(OK)**

Here comes the downside, i try to use the following code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.enable_eager_execution()
saved_model_dir = 'inference_graph/saved_model/'
converter = tf.contrib.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model(saved_model_dir,input_arrays=input_arrays,output_arrays=output_arrays,input_shapes={"image_tensor": [1, 832, 832, 3]})
converter.post_training_quantize = True
```

First I tried without adding input shapes parameter to the function, but it didn't work. Since that time I read that you can write there anything it doesn't matter.

The output till this line:

```
INFO:tensorflow:Saver not created because there are no variables in the graph to restore
INFO:tensorflow:The specified SavedModel has no variables; no checkpoints were restored.
INFO:tensorflow:The given SavedModel MetaGraphDef contains SignatureDefs with the following keys: {'serving_default'}
INFO:tensorflow:input tensors info: 
INFO:tensorflow:Tensor's key in saved_model's tensor_map: inputs
INFO:tensorflow: tensor name: image_tensor:0, shape: (-1, -1, -1, 3), type: DT_UINT8
INFO:tensorflow:output tensors info: 
INFO:tensorflow:Tensor's key in saved_model's tensor_map: num_detections
INFO:tensorflow: tensor name: num_detections:0, shape: (-1), type: DT_FLOAT
INFO:tensorflow:Tensor's key in saved_model's tensor_map: detection_boxes
INFO:tensorflow: tensor name: detection_boxes:0, shape: (-1, 100, 4), type: DT_FLOAT
INFO:tensorflow:Tensor's key in saved_model's tensor_map: detection_scores
INFO:tensorflow: tensor name: detection_scores:0, shape: (-1, 100), type: DT_FLOAT
INFO:tensorflow:Tensor's key in saved_model's tensor_map: detection_classes
INFO:tensorflow: tensor name: detection_classes:0, shape: (-1, 100), type: DT_FLOAT
INFO:tensorflow:Saver not created because there are no variables in the graph to restore
INFO:tensorflow:The specified SavedModel has no variables; no checkpoints were restored.
INFO:tensorflow:Froze 0 variables.
INFO:tensorflow:Converted 0 variables to const ops.
```

Then i wanna convert:

```
tflite_quantized_model = converter.convert()
```

This is the output:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-61a136476642> in <module>
----> 1 tflite_quantized_model = converter.convert()

~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/lite/python/lite.py in convert(self)
    451           input_tensors=self._input_tensors,
    452           output_tensors=self._output_tensors,
--> 453           **converter_kwargs)
    454     else:
    455       # Graphs without valid tensors cannot be loaded into tf.Session since they

~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/lite/python/convert.py in toco_convert_impl(input_data, input_tensors, output_tensors, *args, **kwargs)
    340   data = toco_convert_protos(model_flags.SerializeToString(),
    341                              toco_flags.SerializeToString(),
--> 342                              input_data.SerializeToString())
    343   return data
    344 

~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/lite/python/convert.py in toco_convert_protos(model_flags_str, toco_flags_str, input_data_str)
    133     else:
    134       raise RuntimeError("TOCO failed see console for info.\n%s\n%s\n" %
--> 135                          (stdout, stderr))
    136 
    137 

RuntimeError: TOCO failed see console for info.
```

I can't copy here the console output hence it's more than the 30000 character limit but here you can see it: https://pastebin.com/UyT2x2Vk

Please please help at this point, what should I do to make it work :(

**My config:
Ubuntu 16.04, Tensorflow-GPU 1.12**

Thanks In andvance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Had the same issue last week, resolved it by following the steps described [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/running_on_mobile_tensorflowlite.md).

Basically the issue is that their main script does not support SSD models.
I did not use `bazel` to do this, but the `tflite_convert` utility.

Careful with the `export_tflite_ssd_graph.py` script, read all its options before using it (mainly the --max_detections that saved my life).

Hope this helps.

Edit:
Your step 2 is invalid. A saved_model cannot be converted to a tflite model if it contains a SSD. 
You need to export the trained model.ckpt using the `export_tflite_ssd_graph.py` script and use the `.pb` file created to convert it to tflite with the `tflite_convert` tool.

Comment: Hello, I try with the following command: 

tflite_convert --output_file=models/research/object_detection/tflite_inference/bike.tflite --saved_model_dir=models/research/object_detection/inference_graph/saved_model --input_shapes=1,300,300,3 --input_arrays=image_tensor

but i get the same output as mentioned before. you can see it on the pastebin link :(

Comment: OK, I used the tflite_convert tool! BUT i trained with 19 classes, and now I load back the tflite model with tf.contrib.lite.Interpreter it shows the following inputs and outputs:

Input:

[{'dtype': numpy.float32,
  'index': 253,
  'name': 'normalized_input_image_tensor',
  'quantization': (0.0, 0),
  'shape': array([  1, 300, 300,   3], dtype=int32)}]

Output:

[ {'dtype': numpy.float32,
  'index': 255,
  'name': 'raw_outputs/class_predictions',
  'quantization': (0.0, 0),
  'shape': array([   1, 1917,   20], dtype=int32)}]

What does the 1917 number stands for? :O

Comment: OK, solved every question related to the original post, but the prediction doesn't predict anything :/ did you have something similar?

Comment: Yes I had the pre processing wrong. For it to work I had to convert every pixel rgb value into the range [-1, 1]. If that helps.